# Lychrel Number Program Error

Tags: java

I am trying to make the lychrel number program. but i cannot make it. Criteria is that, list the Lychrel Number which is below in 10000,Lychrel number checking iteration in limited. I have been set it as 30.But i didnt got the solution yet.
number should be listed if the checking completed upto 30 iteration. i didnt get the solutions.help me.

```
public class LychrelNumber {

static final int MAX_NUMBER = 10000;
static final int MAX_ITERATION = 30;
int iterationCount = 0;

void listTheLychrelNymber() throws Exception {
    long i = 0;

    long temp;
    for (int j = 0; j < MAX_NUMBER; j++) {
        iterationCount = 0;
        temp = j;
        for (i = 0; i < MAX_ITERATION; i++) {
            long first = temp;
            long second = reverseTheNumber(temp);
            long third = first + second;
            long fourth = reverseTheNumber(third);
            if (third == fourth) {
                break;
            } else {
                temp = third;
                if (i == MAX_ITERATION) {
                    System.out.println("Lychrel  Numbers are :" + j);
                }
            }
        }
    }


}

long reverseTheNumber(long n) {
    long reverse = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        reverse = reverse * 10;
        reverse = reverse + n % 10;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return reverse;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        LychrelNumber lychrelNumber = new LychrelNumber();
        lychrelNumber.listTheLychrelNymber();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

}

it is build successfull. but i didnt get the output.

Comment: downvoter please add the comment to improve myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

```
 if (i == (MAX_ITERATION-1)) {
    System.out.println("Lychrel Numbers are:" + j);  
 }
```

here i made the mistake in Condition Checking..

Answer (score 0):

Look at your loop of i (I shortened the code a bit)

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX_ITERATION; i++) {
    if (i == MAX_ITERATION) {
        System.out.println("Lychrel  Numbers are :" + j);
    }
}
```

As you see, you stop looping when i reaches MAX_ITERATION but only print the Lychrel number in the loop if i == MAX_ITERATION (which will of course never happen).

Comment: No. You are Wrong. I updated my solution. Thanks anyway. Now Workd